# Get output parameter(type object) form oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a custom `Type` in my oracle database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MYTABLE2 AS object 
( 
 a varchar(20),  b number, c varchar(20),
 CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION MYTABLE2 RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
```

and the following procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COUNT_proc (agein in number, count1 out MYTABLE2) AS 
BEGIN
  count1 := MYTABLE2('',10,'');
  SELECT NAME , AGE ,OCCUPATION 
  INTO count1.a, count1.b, count1.c
  FROM TABLE1 where occupation = 'dev';
END COUNT_proc;
```

I am trying to execute the procedure using c# with the following code:

```
var connectionString = @"myconnectionString";

            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new OleDbCommand("COUNT_proc", connection))
                {
                    var parameterIn = command.CreateParameter();
                    parameterIn.ParameterName = "@in";
                    parameterIn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    parameterIn.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                    parameterIn.Value = 20;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameterIn);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "@count1";
                    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    parameter.DbType = DbType.???; //used object string etc
                    parameter.Size = 20;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //Console.WriteLine(parameter.Value);
                }

                }
            }
```

the problem is that this is throwing an error on the executeNonQuery (I also have used executeScalar and reader) which does not have additional info message nor an ORA error code.When I am using DBType.Object I get this Exception:System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException -> T\u001d\u001c

I also tried to solve this issue by using `oleDbAdapter` and trying to get the results with `Fill(dataTable, "@outputParam")` but this didn't work either.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Why do you use the generic OleDb provider when there are at least two specific providers for Oracle? Probably they have all you need to resolve your requirements

Comment: the main reason is that I want the code to work with other databases also  except oracle.Also OracleCommand etc. has been deprecated by microsoft. Do you have another provider in mind that may help me solve my issue?

Comment: There is the one provided directly from Oracle. However, if you need to have some sort of indipendence from the underlying database I suggest you to investigate the use of an ORM (Entity Framework or others)